# Can't use image as link on NAV

Tags: html, css

Greatings,

I've been working on a nav that has been displaying a weird behaviour, for some reason I can't click on my logo(an image) for it to link to another page. However I can actually drag the image around when I hold my mouse on it, so I suppose it doesn't have anything to do with Z-index.

If anyone could help me it would be great, I have been strugling with this for days..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Responsive Sticky Navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font- 
  awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
        <header>

              <nav>

                    <div class="menu-icon">
                          <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="logo">
                          <a ref="#"><img src="logo.png" style="width: 
                          100px"></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu">
                          <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                          </ul>
                    </div>
              </nav>

        </header>

        <div class="content">
              <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
                    typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
                    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown 
                    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a 
                    type specimen book. It has survived not only five 
                    centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
                    remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in 
                    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing 
                    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop 
                   publishing software like 
                    Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
              </p>
        </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  // Menu-toggle button

  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
              $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
        });
  });

  // Scrolling Effect

  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop()) {
              $('nav').addClass('black');
        }

        else {
              $('nav').removeClass('black');
        }
  })


  </script>

</body>
</html>


  html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1527845599/hero_yankaq.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 4em auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.logo {
line-height: 60px;
position: fixed;
float: left;
margin: 13px 46px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
```

}

```
.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

 @media(max-width: 786px) {

  .logo {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 16px;
  }

  nav ul {
        max-height: 0px;
        background: #000;
  }

  nav.black ul {
        background: #000;
  }

  .showing {
        max-height: 34em;
  }

  nav ul li {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 24px;
        text-align: center;
  }

  .menu-icon {
        display: block;
  }

}
```

Comment: Provide a link.

Comment: where is your code? how should we check without code..

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring below pen and highlighted logo image
https://codepen.io/wristcutter69/pen/zZNqpo

[image]

Here you link a tag not on logo image. it should be like this to make it link.

```
<a href="www.google.com"><img src="images/logo_multimedia_house.png"></a>
```

I hope will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an anchor tag around the image to create a "clickable" image.

```html
    <a href="#mylink" title="Logo"><img src="https://www.placecage.com/gif/284/196" alt="Logo"/></a>
```

The dragging is a browser feature to save the image to your computer by dragging it out of the browser window on to the desktop for example.

Comment: I know, it's what I've done, but odly enought it doesn't work... it's like it is not validated or something for some reason...

Comment: Your example says `ref` and not `href` for your anchor tag of the logo.

`<div class="logo">
                          <a href="#"><img src="logo.png" style="width: 
                          100px"></a>
                    </div>`